# count average sentence per paragraph

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file from which I need to count the average number of words per sentence and the average number of sentences per paragraph, where a paragraph is any number of sentences followed by a blank line or by the end of the text and also sentence is a sequence of words followed by either a full-stop, comma or exclamation mark, which in turn must be followed either by a quotation mark (so the sentence is the end of a quote or spoken utterance), or white space (space, tab or new-line character).kindly don't use any module like regex.

I tried using the following code but sometimes it says zerdivision error but I got how I can find avg word count for a sentence but I'm still having problem in finding the avg number of sentences per paragraph with the condition given above.

```
with open("/Users/abhishekabhishek/downloads/l.txt") as f:
      # calculate number of lines for that text
      total_number_of_sent = f.read().split()
      for line in total_number_of_sent:
             total_sum += sum(line.split())
      average_number_sentences = total_sum/total_number_of_sent
# this is just a sample sentence from the file not the whole file
sample_sentence = "I am not a proper archM-CM-&ologist nor an      anthropologist nor an ethnologist"
# it gives me the average word count for that sentence
average_word_count = sum(len(word) for word in        f.read().split())/len(f.read().split())
print(round(average_word_count, 2))
```

it should return something like this 
these are just sample values what it should look like when we will get correct result not the actual answer because I don't know what the actual numbers would be as I haven't calculated any of these I just tried that on the sample sentence.
{"avg_words_per_sentence": 5.42,"avg_sentences_per_paragraph":8}

This is one of the paragraphs from the text that I have hope that will do.

```
Phasellus fringilla luctus magna, a finibus justo dapibus a. Nam risus felis, rhoncus eget diam sit amet, congue facilisis nibh. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Praesent consequat euismod diam, eget volutpat magna convallis at. Mauris placerat pellentesque imperdiet. Nulla porta scelerisque enim, et scelerisque neque bibendum in. Proin eget turpis nisi. Suspendisse ut est a erat egestas eleifend at euismod arcu. Donec aliquet, nisi sed faucibus condimentum, nisi metus dictum eros, nec dignissim justo odio id nulla. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Maecenas sollicitudin, justo id elementum eleifend, justo neque aliquet nibh, finibus malesuada metus erat eget neque. Suspendisse nec auctor orci. Aenean et vestibulum nulla. Nullam hendrerit augue tristique, commodo metus id, sodales lorem. Etiam feugiat dui est, vitae auctor risus convallis non.
```

Comment: `total_sum/total_number_of_sent` should be `total_sum/len(total_number_of_sent)`.

Comment: `sum(line.split())` should be `len(line.split())`

Comment: I tried this also def sent_count():
    my_file = file()
    new_dic = {}
    values = ".!,' "
    total = sum(my_file.count(x) for x in values)
    paragraphs = my_file.count("\n")
    value = (round(total / paragraphs, 2))
    new_dic["average_sentences"] = value
    return new_dic

Comment: This won't work: `sum(len(word) for word in f.read().split())/len(f.read().split())`. The first `f.read()` reads the entire file, the second `f.read()` has nothing left to read.

Comment: Put `f.read().split()` in a variable, then use that.